# Android: Improve WebView speed loading local HTML files?

Tags: android, webview

I'm embedding some HTML content (stored locally) in my android application and using a WebView to render it. I'm finding that I always "see" the HTML content being loaded (ie. white bg before the page is rendered), even though it's located as an "asset" inside the app.

To mask this "issue", I'm currently hiding the WebView, sub-classing the onPageFinished() method and showing a ProgressDialog until I the page completes.  Which is annoying coz we're only talking seconds here.

I've seen suggestion of using the following:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

...but this doesn't seem to help.

Has anyone managed to overcome this?
(If I could change the WebView's initial bg colour, it might be an improvement, but not ideal)

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could have a very simple page with the basic initial color and load that first. Then you load your real HTML.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but essentially I'm already doing that as my HTML pages ARE very simple. :o(

Comment: I get the same thing even on recent devices - and with the new-ish 2d acceleration enabled.